# Axios Default URL and Parameters with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, axios

I'm trying to work laravel and react app.
In my app axios default setting not working.
please check my screenshot code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnjTb.png.)

This is my bootstrap.js
I'm  also trying `window.axios.defaults.baseUrl= 'myrooturl'`.
It's not work
The below photo is an API call.
Axios were called `localhost/api/brand` this is not default baseUrl.

Answer (score 0):

Have you use laravel-mix? Do you run `npm run dev`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to log `window.axios`.
I think you should provide more info, then everyone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```html
axios.get('/api/brand')
```

or see this demo  https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/175#issuecomment-165521644